# Probability with looping outcomes (for example, how many times to reroll dice to achieve 90% certainty I will get number 6)

Tags: probability

For the example above, I believe the number of attempts to achieve 90% certainty that I will get a 6 at least once is $$n=\ln\left(\frac{1-90\%}{1-\frac{1}{6}}\right)\approx12.6$$

In this game I play, you can upgrade weapons, but if the upgrade fails, it will downgrade 3 times.

```
Level 0 to  1 - 90% success -  9% nothing happens - 1% break
Level 1 to  2 - 50% success - 50% downgrade to level 0
Level 2 to  3 - 50% success - 50% downgrade to level 0
Level 3 to  4 - 40% success - 60% downgrade to level 0
Level 4 to  5 - 30% success - 70% downgrade to level 1
Level 5 to  6 - 30% success - 70% downgrade to level 2
Level 6 to  7 - 30% success - 70% downgrade to level 3
Level 7 to  8 - 20% success - 80% downgrade to level 4
Level 8 to  9 - 20% success - 80% downgrade to level 5
Level 9 to 10 - 15% success - 85% downgrade to level 6
```

Each upgrade requires an ore.

How many ores (and how many weapons required, considering there is a remote chance to break) to achieve level 10 with 90% certainty for example.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean $\frac{\log(1/10)}{\log(5/6)}$ but you got the right answer, so it must be a typo.  As to the rest of it, I don't understand.  What is an ore?  What is a weapon?  What level are you starting from?

Answer (score 3):

Weapon upgrades can be modeled as a discrete-time Markov chain with the transition matrix $$\mathcal P =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{100} & \frac{9}{100} & \frac{9}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{3}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{7}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{7}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{7}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{17}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{20} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the first row corresponds to the absorbing state of the weapon breaking, and the last row corresponds to the absorbing state of the weapon having reached level $10$.  In this case, we are interested in the mean number of steps needed to reach maximal upgrade status without the weapon breaking, starting from Level $0$.  *Mathematica* gives this as $$\frac{614006566}{2050521} \approx 299.439.$$  However, this does not take into account the fact that the probability of ever reaching this state is quite low:  it is only $\frac{1215}{683507} \approx 0.0017776$, whereas the probability the weapon will eventually break is $\frac{682292}{683507} \approx 0.998222$.  A modification of $\mathcal P$ so that we start over with a new weapon if a weapon breaks, shows that the mean number of steps to reach maximal upgrade status becomes $$\frac{198613522}{1215} \approx 163467.919.$$  That means, on average, you would need to spend this many ores to get a single Level $10$ weapon.  To have at least $90\%$ probability of getting a Level $10$ weapon, that is to say, you want the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile of the first passage time distribution to reach this state, you'd have to spend even more:  $376387$ ores are needed.  Unfortunately, I cannot calculate the number of weapons you'd have to break before this happens, but it would be substantial; a good estimate would be $561$, the ratio of the limiting probabilities of breakage versus maximal upgrade.

Comment: This is an incredible answer! (My apologies for reading and replying this late.) It is very detailed, with specific answer, as well as the steps.
I'm not familiar with discrete-time Markov chain with the transition matrix but I can look it up.
Thank you so much!