# Is there an analytical solution to this probabilistic problem?

Tags: probability, simulation, gambling

I am a big fan of MMORPGs, and this one, Cabal Online, has a particularly punishing upgrade system.

- Items can be upgraded to increase their stats, ranging from level 0 to level 15 (for simplicity).
- Upgrading costs cores (can be interpreted as currency).
- Attempting an upgrade can result can result in the item's level going up (+1), remaining the same (0), or going down (-1 or -2).
- The probabilities of these are summarized in the table below:

[image: Table of Rates]

The question now is:
What is the expected number of cores to upgrade an item from level 0 to level 15?

---

I initially tried approaching this using a binomial distribution approach, as it involved successes and trials, and failures, but realized that the trials change depending on the item grade and are not independent.

I then tried drawing it as a probability tree of sorts, but ended up with infinite recursion.

I realize that my current knowledge is not adequate to tackle such complex problems, *analytically* unfortunately.

However, I have managed to arrive at a value of 22,000 using a simulation that involved multiple nested for loops.

I'm now curious about whether there is a way to analytically calculate the number of cores required.

Comment: What are MMORPG ?

Comment: Massively Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game - It's a kind of game where many players can interact with each other and work together to achieve common goals.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: I think dynamic programming/ viterbi is the way to go, but I haven't thought through the details.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743425/probability-with-looping-outcomes-for-example-how-many-times-to-reroll-dice-to/3743480#3743480

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An analytic solution is possible by the method of Markov chains, but we will need some mathematical software such as Matlab, Octave, or Mathematica.

Let's number the stages from $1$, corresponding to zero weapons, to $16$, corresponding to 15 weapons, and let $\mathbf{P}$ be the $16$ by $16$ matrix of one step transition probabilities; i.e., $\mathbf{P}_{i,j}$ is the probability of moving from stage $i$ to stage $j$. So from the table in the problem statement,

$$\mathbf{P} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.27 & 0.21 & 0 & 0.52 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.36 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.45 & 0.19 & 0 & 0.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.48 & 0.16 & 0 & 0.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.48 & 0.16 & 0 & 0.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.48 & 0.16 & 0 & 0.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.14 & 0 & 0.36 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.14 & 0 & 0.36 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.14 & 0 & 0.36 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Let's also number the steps of the game starting at $0$, so at step $0$ the player is in stage $1$, and let $\pi_n$ be the vector of probabilities of being in each stage at step $n$, written as a $1$ by $16$ matrix, so
$$\pi_0 = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]$$
Given these definitions, the probabilities at step $n$ are given by
$$\pi_n = \pi_0 \mathbf{P}^n$$
It remains to work in the cost in number of cores associated with each stage. Let
$$c = (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,0)^T$$
Then the expected cost of being at step $n$, disregarding the cost required by previous steps, is
$$x_n = \pi_0 \mathbf{P}^n c$$

We want to know the expected total cost,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \pi_0 \mathbf{P}^n c = \pi_0 \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \mathbf{P}^n \right) c = \pi_0 (I-\mathbf{P})^{-1} c$$

Using some mathematical software to invert $I-\mathbf{P}$ and perform the matrix multiplications involved, we find that the expected number of cores required to reach stage $16$ is
$$\pi_0 (I-\mathbf{P})^{-1} c = \boxed{24120.6}$$

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! Please allow me some time to read this solution more thoroughly, many of the concepts currently lie beyond my knowledge.